# Meteor project deployment and mup setup command give "sshpass required for password based authentication" error

Tags: mongodb, deployment, meteor, meteor-up, sshpass

I am trying to deploy a Meteor based project. I'm using nitrous.io, digital ocean for the server, and compose.io for MongoDB.

I already wanted to finish my deployment and run the "mup setup" command and had got this message:

> Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
>
> ---
>
> sshpass required for password based authentication

After trying to install sshpass from here http://git.io/_vHbvQ, and running the command "apt-get install sshpass" I have got the following errors:

> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission
>   denied)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are
>   you root?

I also tried another way to install sshpass (also described here http://git.io/_vHbvQ) by creating the folder configure:

> action@steady-meteor-55-179639:~/workspace/MeteorProject/configure$
>   sudo make install
>
> -----                                                                                                                                                                              WARNING: sudo access is not available; running without sudo.
>
> -----                                                                                                                                                                              make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
>
>   action@steady-meteor-55-179639:~/workspace/MeteorProject/configure$
>   make install
>
>   make: *** No rule to make target`install'.  Stop.

**Configure folder is located in this way:** ~/workspace/MeteorProject/configure/sshpass-1.05

**My mup.json file looks like this:**

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "XXX.XXX.XX.XX",
      "username": "root",
      "password": "123456789"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Try installing `sshpass` under a `root` or a user with administrative access or with `sudo apt-get install sshpass`

Comment: @Akshat Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, root access and apt-get isn't offered at this time in nitrous.io, so I don't have access to 'sudo' or 'apt-get'.

Comment: In that scenario there is no other way to get passed this other than using a private key to authenticate to your server. Luckily its not too hard : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: @Akshat thanks Akshat. I did what explained in the article. What are the next steps? I used the 'mup setup' command again, and it is again requires ssh-pass

Comment: Configure your mup.json to use the keyfile/pem instead of the password and be sure to comment the password out.

Comment: @Akshat **DONE!!! You helped me to solve this problem. Thank you!** How can I mark your answers as a solution to the problem I had?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just will conclude what @Akshat explained (special thanks to @Akshat for his help)

`root` access and `apt-get` isn't offered at this time in nitrous.io

In order to solve this problem, you need to create private key to authenticate to your server. 
Hare explained how doing it: digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

After you created private keys, you need to configure your mup.json to use the keyfile/pem (which probably you have as a comment, just delete comment signs) instead of the password and be sure to comment the password out.

That is all!